# How to group and sum by foreign key?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have these two models in my Rails app:

```
class Person < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :payments

end
```

---

```
class Payment < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :person

end
```

---

How can I group the `payments` by `person` and order them by `amount`?

Right now I have...

```
Payment.group(:person_id).sum("amount")
```

...which works but doesn't include the persons' names. It returns something like this:

```
{ 1 => 1200.00, 2 => 2500.00 }
```

How can I replace the `IDs` / integers with the persons' names and also sort the whole thing by `amount`?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Those IDs are the record IDs. You'll need to fetch them back or use a `pluck()` that's more specific.

Comment: What level of data do you actually want is just name => value acceptable or are you looking for formal objects

Comment: @engineersmnky: Sorry for the late reply. I actually need a hash in the format `{name => value, name => value}` to create a chart powered by Chart.js. Thanks for your answers so far, I am still trying to figure out which one is the best.

Comment: That is going to be tricky unless you can guarantee that the person's name will always be unique.

Comment: @engineersmnky: I can *almost* guarantee that! What would happen if there are two people with the same name (which is very unlikely...)?

Comment: The key for a Hash must be unique so one of 2 things could happen depending on how the Hash is constructed 1) the second key would overwrite the first 2) they would be summed together under a single key and you would lose the record for one person while compounding the payments of another

Answer (score 3):

Just be a bit more specific:

```
Payment.select('people.name, SUM(payments.amount)').joins(:person).group(:person_id)
```

Assuming that the *persons* table is named `people` in your application.

Comment: In this case it seems like it would be easier to go the other way e.g. `Person.joins(:payments).select('people.*, SUM(payments.amount) as total_payments').group(:id)` then these a formal `Person` objects with a virtual attribute of `total_payments` and just since I abhor raw SQL I would use `select(Person.arel_attribute(Arel.star), Payment.arel_attribute(:amount).sum.as('total_payments'))`

Answer (score 2):

This will return the ActiveRecord::Relation that you can work with:

```
Person.joins(:payments).group('persons.id').select("persons.id, persons.name, sum(payments.amount) as amounts_summ")
```

**Only** for unique `name` fields:
Assuming you have `name` property for Person model, solution can be like this:

```rb
Payment.joins(:person).group(:name).order('sum_amount DESC').sum(:amount)
```

It generates query

```sql
SELECT SUM("payments"."amount") AS sum_amount, "name" AS name FROM "payments" INNER JOIN "persons" ON "persons"."id" = "payments"."persons_id" GROUP BY "name" ORDER BY sum_amount DESC
```

and return hash like this:

```
=> {"Mike"=>22333.0, "John"=>5676.0, "Alex"=>2000.0, "Carol"=>2000.0}
```

Comment: And assuming that a persons name is unique for all records

Comment: oh, yeah) need some changes to be done, you are right)

Comment: @engineersmnky, looks like you are right, and it's easier to take result from `Person` model, added the query that return relation to work with, and the initial code maybe can help somebody to group by email or other unique field)